# Why can't the baseclass object can't access the childclass's method?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

Am a newbie to OOP
 The below code has the super class(schools) and its properties inherited in the childclass(teachers). I have created an object for the baseclass 
`a = schools('jack','m2',2)`. It creates an instance and initializes instance variables but when with this object when I try to access the childclass methods it fails with the following error:

> AttributeError: schools instance has no attribute 'show'.

```
class schools:
   def __init__(self,name,sex,rank):
       self.name = name
       self.sex = sex


    def saying(self):
        print self.name

class teachers(schools):

   def show(self):
       print self.sex

a = schools('jack','m2',2)
a.saying()
a.show()
```

Comment: Because the base class is not the extended class. Why do you expect the methods on `teachers` to be available on `schools`?

Comment: If you want to have an object that supports the `show()` method, create a `teachers` instance.

Comment: More fundamentally, your inheritance hierarchy is broken. A teacher is not a type of school.

Comment: You are confusing how inheritance works. Every `teacher` object has the `show` function, but not every `school` object. And most certainly, making `teacher` a subclass of `school` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The child-class (or subclass, or descendant) builds upon the base class (superclass, or ancestor). So the child-class can do anything  its superclass can do, *plus* what it adds itself.

It doesn't change the superclass, though. The superclass can only do what is defined in the superclass (and in the superclass's ancestors).

So, Schools can do saying()
Teachers can do saying(), *and* show().

Schools do not know that one of its subclasses has defined show().

Answer (score 1):

The child class has access to the parent (base) class through inheritance. The parent doesn't have a clue that it has children or what their properties are.

```
class Schools:
    def __init__(self,name,sex,rank):
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex

    def saying(self):
        print self.name
# end class Schools

class Teachers(schools):

    def show(self):
        print self.sex

    # Teachers has and can use the methods and properties below because it is inherited
    # def __init__(self,name,sex,rank):
    #     self.name = name
    #     self.sex = sex
    # 
    # def saying(self):
    #     print self.name

# end class Teachers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    teacher = Teachers('jack','m2',2)
    teacher.saying()
    teacher.show()
```

This is useful for developers to build on top of things that others have done. The classic example is vehicles. Below shows some different things used in inheritance. Tractor, Car, and Van both inherit the Vehicle, so they have the Vehicle's properties. Tractor, Car, and Van are siblings, but they don't know anything about each other. They have different methods and will be used for different things. However, they all share some common factors, so we inherit those common factors from Vehicle. SportsCar has Vehicle's attributes and methods, and it has Car's attributes and methods.

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()

        self.name = name
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    # end Constructor

    def drive(self, x, y):
        """Drive the car to the given x,y point."""
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    # end drive
# end Vehicle

class Tractor(Vehicle):
    pass
# end class Tractor

class Van(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name, passengers=1):
        super().__init__(name) # Call parent method

        self.max_capacity = 5
        self.passengers = passengers
    # end Constructor

    def drive(self, x, y):
        """We have passengers now, so we care about safety."""
        if self.passengers <= self.max_capacity:
            super().drive(x, y) # Use parent's (Vehicle) drive method
    # end drive
# end class Van

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

        self.speed = 0
    # end Constructor

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed

    def drive_fast(self, x, y, speed):
        self.setSpeed(speed)
        self.drive(x, y)
# end class Car

class SportsCar(Car):
    pass
# end class SportsCar
```

All of this code is Python 3.x, so you will have to change how you use the super method.

```
super(Vehicle, self).drive(x, y)
```